# apache virtual host status

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

I'm trying to get status information about my Apache virtual hosts.

I currently setup apache (2.4) mod_status on my apache server hosting several virtual hosts. All retrievable through a single IP-address, but with different ServerNames.

When I retrieve the server-status page of the different virtual hosts, the information seems to be more or less the same. So for now I've the feeling that server-status is only returning information about the apache server as a whole, not per virtual host.

How can I setup apache mod-status in such a way that I get status information per Virtual Host?